# Linking a header file with shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have a library with .so file and a header(.h) file. In order to use the library, I have to include the header file and then link to the library, is there a way to get rid of the header file and directly use the functions, there are some function declarations and enums defined in the .h file, is there a way to combine the .h and .so file to generate one .so file that I can use directly ?

Comment: No, there is not. The idea of the .h file is to inform the user of the library of the functions and datatypes your library makes available. The compiler needs this info to check if the library is used correctly.

Comment: And why would you want that?

Comment: I was just wondering, seems like it is not possible. Thankyou ! I am new to C

Comment: You can always *copy-paste* the contents of the header files into each and every one of your C files that requires them. The `#include` mechanism is for those who don't like repeating themselves...

Comment: But yes, unlike Java classes, Python .pyc's and so on, the Unix/Linux shared objects do not contain sufficient metadata.